# How can I validate on server side a input text where I have tags separated by commas?

Tags: php, post, explode

The user will input on a text field something like this:

```
$list = "hello, internet, connection, wireless"
```

I'm getting them out with the following:

```
$tags = explode(',', $list);
```

The problem is that before I do that, I need to validate whether the format of the string captured in the `$_POST` actually has that format. Any ideas how can I do that? I'm not an experienced PHP programmer, I usually just work on front end development.

The user can input more than 4 tags, it's not always going to be 4, he can put 5 or 6 with a maximum of 7, the output I want is to have on an array, all the words in the string, the background for this is that I'm making a simple helpdesk, where users can ask a question, and I will return all the results according to the found tags in the question the user has input.

So I really need to make sure that when the ADMIN of this helpdesk is typing the tags, they're on that format:

```
$data = "internet, connection, wireless, internet-explorer";
```

Comment: It will always contain 4 items?

Comment: You can use regular expressions: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php. If you want someone to help you write the expression, you need to give more info on what the expected format is.

Comment: What other formats can the string have? If `$tags[0] == $list`, you can be sure it didn't contain commas. You can test for a substring with `strpos`. I would discourage using regex here, unless there is a very good reason to use it. Without more information I can't really give a good answer.

Comment: You could show the Result of the split and let the admin confirm if everthing is alright ;)

Answer (score 0):

I depends if the contents everytime 4 Elements.

```
<?php

    $list = "hello, internet, connection, wireless";
    echo substr_count($list,', '); // return 3 commas

?>
```

or you count the elements:

```
<?php
     $list = "hello, internet, connection, wireless";
     $result = explode(', ',$list);
     if(count($result) ==4 ){
         echo "right format";
     }
?>
```

Edit:

When you don't need the whitespaces:

```
<?php
     $list = "hello, internet, connection, wireless";
     $result = array_map('trim',explode(",",$list)); 
     if(count($result) ==4 ){
         echo "right format";
     }
?>
```

Comment: What if I input `foo, b,a,r, baz, bak`?

Comment: @AmalMurali If that is a correct format, splitting and testing should happen with `", "` instead.

Comment: @Amal Murali, i have edited my post, but i don't know if Yisera needs the whitespace ;)

Comment: @demonking don't really need them, that is quite useful actually. The only thing I'm actually thinking now is, what happens when he applies a comma on a wrong part? That would be really bad because what would get saved on the database will be something completely different than what is intended.

Comment: I don't know, the list is for, but i think this is something like a category list? If yes, mabye you could check something against them?